# Metric on $\mathbb{Z} ^+$ . GRE math subject test

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{Z}^+$ be the set of positive integers and let $d$ be the metric on $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ defined by

$$ 
d(n,m) =
 \begin{cases} 
0 &,\text{ if }\; m=n \\
1 &, \text{ if }\; m \ne n \end{cases}
$$

for all $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ which of the following are true about the metric space $(\mathbb{Z}^+, d)$?

1. If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ then $\{ n \}$ is open.
2. Every subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is closed.
3. Every real valued function defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is continuous.

My thoughts. $\{n\}$ is open since it is the ball $B(n,1)=\{m\in \mathbb{Z}^+ : d(n,m)<1\}=\{n\}$ so it is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence the first and the second and the third are correct?

Comment: Correct. The topology induced by $d$ is exactly the discrete topology.

Comment: @Hermès how can I sign this question as solved?

Comment: @Hermès too humble to post as answer? :P

Comment: You should answer your own question in this cases. And should make it most explicit as possible on how you did your calculations